How to disable anti-aliasing?
Side Note: I think I've solved the problem, so only respond if you really want to.

This is a picture of my profile picture. Basically a dithering effect; and posterization effect with two values per color channel (0,255). There are some undesired issues though.
Issues:

The bit depth supposed to be 1bit, either 255 or 0 on each color channel. For some reason it isn't, because the green does not at all look like #00FF00, and I'm not sure why.

The other thing is the edges of the render (between the model and bg). There is some darkened pixels in relation to everything else.


I'm not sure what is causing this. I know the second problem must be by anti-aliasing, but I'm not entirely sure the first problem is the same thing. There is another question very similar to this (500+ views), but it has gone unanswered for
5 years. So basically, what I'm saying is you should help me.
Here's my blender file:

Sorry, I do not really understand your setup, what the result is supposed to be. First of all, the image texture is not packed into the file so I cannot get the intended output. Without it the scaling by 16 is not really clear either. And why are you multiplying the red channel by 80? And which green does not look like #00FF00? The Base Color in the Principled BSDF? Because it is not, it is #00FF94 (and the yellow is #FFC500 and the blue #0074FF). Apart from that, maybe you should set the Color Management > View Transform to Standard instead of AgX.

Another thing I do not understand in your nodetree is, it seems like you want to have three colors there from the Principled BSDF, green, yellow and blue. But if you only want the colors, why don't take a simple RGB node? And why do you convert it with a Shader to RGB node? This converts the reflections from the perfectly smooth surface (Roughness = 0) into the color, together with the reflected grey world background which is another reason that the colors might not look as you set them in the Base Color.

For the anti-aliasing: in the Render Properties under Film, set the Filter Size to the minimum (I think the slider goes down to 0.01 px, but manually you could even enter 0 px but both should be okay). But the curved edges and smooth shading will also create a darkening effect around the borders (why are they curved when you want a pixelated result with no anti-aliasing?)

@GordonBrinkmann Sorry, I've only used blender for 5-6 days now, so I don't always know the best way to do things. The image:(drive.google.com/file/d/1CakOxpWYSAFGsSQmh6-jCGceCLzfvTXj/view?usp=sharing)      I just updated the file to bugfix some things. The filter size reduction worked (thanks!), that reduced the palette to strictly 8 colors (but apparently it's not, as I'll get to later). For your question on the principled BSDF color, it may have been confusing because i forgot to link the image. What i'm talking about is the individual pixels on the render.

@GordonBrinkmann As I said, there is not in fact 8 colors. (well technically theres no magenta which makes it 7 but thats not my point). My point is that when I take the render into an image editor, there is actually 30. This is really annoying and I'm pretty sure it is caused by pixels actually having two colors. If you click on the camera icon, you can see that some pixels actually have a bit of red or whatever in them and not fully one color. This is because I am only pixelating one of the inputs for the less than node and not the BSDF. I'm not sure how you would pixelate the BSDF.

@GordonBrinkmann I was thinking of just not dealing with that and just making sure there was only 8 colors after the render using compositing (which would fix the color of the green), but for some reason the posterize node dosen't seem to be doing anything. When I set the steps to 2, it just does not at all help with limiting the colors. I might have to put that on a different question. Oh yeah, using the BSDF instead of a plain color was to add shading. You can see some darker bits in the render, and that could not be achieved without using the BSDF.
